# Creating a toggle data-* attributes jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a new project and using 'data-js' attributes. I currently am toggling each data-js attribute manually, so for instance:

```
$(this).attr('data-js', $(this).attr('data-js') == 'unstar' ? 'star' : 'unstar')
```

I have a 'shell' for creating a plugin-style extension of jQuery, that looks like this:

```
!function($) {
            $.fn.toggleData = function(options) {
                var settings = $.extend({
                    someEvent: function() {
                        alert('default')
                    }
                }, options)

                return this.each(function() {
                    settings.someEvent()
                })
            }
        }(jQuery)
```

So what I am basically wanting is to create a function that would give me the following, which would be reusable across all data-js attributes:

```
$('[data-js=unstar]').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleData('unstar', 'star')

})
```

Any thoughts on how to do this, or a better way!... Are much appreciated.

Comment: I think the approach you are following is best

Comment: @Madhu - thanks, but I don't want to keep repeating the same line of code - I need to create a reusable function for it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you're after? I've just put the clone in to demonstrate that it work on all future [data-js] datatypes.

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-js]', function () {

if ($(this).attr('data-js') == 'unstar' || $(this).attr('data-js') == 'star') {

    $(this).attr('data-js', $(this).attr('data-js') == 'unstar' ? 'star' : 'unstar');


    alert($(this).attr('data-js'));
    $(this).clone().insertAfter(this);

}
});
```

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your answer. I'm after a plugin type re-usable function that isn't limited to the data-js values. It would need to be dynamic for reuse! :)